# Repeat header rows when exporting to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, export, itext

I'm trying to export a table to a pdf document.

My problem is that the header row is only in the first page, and i can't figure out how to make it repeat.

Couldn't find a solution online.
I'm using ASP.NET and the export to pdf is with iTextSharp.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [set format of header row in itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838145/set-format-of-header-row-in-itext). In the answer to this question, the concept of header rows is explained. This question was selected for the book [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](https://leanpub.com/itext_so). You only need to chance the Java syntax into C# syntax, for instance `table.HeaderRows = 1;` instead of `table.setHeaderRows(1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a `PdfPTable` object, you can define a row as a header row like this:

```
table.HeaderRows = 1;
```

If you need more than one header row, change `1` into another number.

If you also need footer rows, you need to be careful. Suppose that you want 2 header rows and 1 footer row, then you need something like this:

```
table.HeaderRows = 3; // 2 header rows + 1 footer row
table.FooterRows = 1;
```

I know this is awkward, but there are historical reasons for this. You need to set the `HeaderRows` to the number of all rows that need to be repeated (header and footer rows) and then define the number of actual footer rows.

Comment: I think table.HeaderRows does not work when SelectedRows() function is used. Is there any way, other than creating a separate table for the headers and add it manually at the top of each page, when splitting a table with SelectedRows