# ITextsharp Table - Getting number of page that a table would fit in

Tags: pdf, itext

Here is what I am doing with ITextSharp.
1. Read a list of data from SQL Table
2. Generate table with iTextSharp using the above data
3. Add the table into a PDF

The table is overflow to the next page automatically when I add the  table to PDF. Number of pages is unknown until I add the table into the PDF. I would like to add header to each page.

Is there anyway I can add the header in each page?

Below is the code to generate the PDF table.

```
public bool CreateProductsCoverPage(ProductDataList products, string inFile, string outFile, out string error)
{
    error = "";
    try
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
        var size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        var document = new Document(size);
        var rect = reader.GetBoxSize(1, "trim");
        var fs = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        //Open the document
        document.Open();
        // the pdf content
        var cb = writer.DirectContent;

        //Define the fonts for title
        var headerFont = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA
                                    , 12
                                    , iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD
                                    , BaseColor.BLACK
                                );

        //Define the fonts for text
        var detailsFont = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA
                                    , 10
                                    , iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL
                                    , BaseColor.BLACK
                                );

        PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(4);
        var pageWdith = reader.GetPageSize(1).Width * 0.95f;
        var ratio = pageWdith / 10;
        float[] widths = new float[] { 1f * ratio, 2f * ratio, 6f * ratio, 1f * ratio };
        Rectangle pSize = new Rectangle(reader.GetPageSize(1).Height * 0.9f, reader.GetPageSize(1).Width * 0.9f);

        PdfTable.SetWidthPercentage(widths, reader.GetPageSize(1));
        PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;


        //Add Header of the pdf table
        PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("QTY", headerFont)));
        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);

        PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("ISBN", headerFont)));
        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);

        PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("AUTHOR/TITLE", headerFont)));
        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);

        PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("BAY", headerFont)));
        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);

        var recordCount = products.Count;

        //How add the data from datatable to pdf table
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            foreach (var prop in product.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(prop.GetValue(product, null).ToString(), detailsFont)));
                PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
            }
            PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 15f; // Give some space after the text or it may overlap the table
        }

        document.Add(PdfTable);

        // create the new page and add it to the pdf
        var page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);


        document.Close();
        fs.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify your question. I've read it a couple of times and I don't understand the question. You should clarify. (Why are you using `PdfReader`?)

Comment: If you're just trying to do a [_page x of y_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9845722/231316) I'd suggest just performing two passes, it is much simpler.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie. I have modified my question

Comment: @AlanB Please read the questions and examples tagged [header](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/header) on the [official developers web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/). I'll search for the answer that corresponds best and mark your question as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set format of header row in itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838145/) although your question isn't clear enough to decide which option is best: (1) using a repeating table header, (2) using page events, (3) adding a header in a second pass as @ChrisHaas suggests. One thing is certain though: you should throw away `cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0)` and all related lines. There is no reasons whatsoever to use that method. If you see this as option (4), I strongly suggest that you abandon that option. Please read the documentation first.