# How to put table in proper way with itextpdf in android?

Tags: sqlite, itext

I want to export my Sqlite to a PDF. I am able to do it but instead of putting the result in just one row, it puts the the result in the other column i have. What I want is to fill the row in the same column(incremente the rows)with the database results. This is what I have, Can you help me with this?

```
 db = new Database(FirstActivity.this);
        Cursor c = bd.getGroupsNamesMachines();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);


        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("groups"));
        cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("machines"));
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

                String groups = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("groupname"));


                cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(groups));
                table.addCell(cell3);

            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }

        cell.setColspan(1);
        cell2.setColspan(2);
        cell3.setColspan(1);
        table.addCell(cell);
        table.addCell(cell2);
        table.addCell(cell3);
```

Comment: Please explain how you *want* your result to look. Your current code results in a weird output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/api-documentation/itext-7-java), or watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c) (before the first 10 minutes are over, you'll know how to create a table that shows all the states of the US). The code for that example can be found here: [set format of header row using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838145/set-format-of-header-row-in-itext)

In your case, you are doing something really strange. You create a table with 2 columns. That's OK if each record has two fields. However, you add the body cells before you add the header cells. I think you're trying to create a header row with 3 columns (which is illogical), and you probably don't complete the last row (and iText only adds complete rows by default).

You need something like this:

```
// Table
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
// Header
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("groups"));
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("machines"));
table.addCell(cell1);
table.addCell(cell2);
// Data
db = new Database(FirstActivity.this);
Cursor c = db.getGroupsNamesMachines();
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String group = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("groupname"));
        cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(group));
        table.addCell(cell1);
        String machine = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("machinename"));
        cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
        table.addCell(cell2);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
document.add(table);
```

I don't know if the database code is OK; it's your responsibility to know how to get the correct data from the database, but please compare your very asymmetric code with the logical code I changed it into.

- First define the header, and add it to the table,
- Then loop over the data, and add the data row by row,
- Never add more cells to a row than there are columns!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling to understand how the columns/rows worked. Good library you´ve created ;)

Comment: And how can I get dynamic cells instead of only two? Can you help me? :/

Comment: When you perform a query, you always know how many fields each record has. You need to define the table with that number of fields: `new PdfPTable(numFields)`. You can't expect iText to ""guess" how many columns are needed; you need to define that yourself (and you *can* define that yourself, because you *have* that information).