# How do I write text over an image in ITextpdf?

Tags: java, itext

I'm developing on iTextPdf in Java.

I want written text absolute position on the image. Like this:

[image]

In the tutorial, I tried to use `showTextAligned` in `DrawContext` to lay out the text, but I can not control the Font.

Please tell me how you can have multiple texts in the desired location with the desired font color and size on the image.

Comment: You don't show any code. This most likely causes the answers to be only loosely related to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You may use iText PDFstamper on a generated pdf.
For more details, please refer to the following:
[Changing the font color and size when using FontSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857273/changing-the-font-color-and-size-when-using-fontselector)
https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-watermark-page-opaque-image

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;


class PDFStamperExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("HelloWorld.pdf");
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream("HelloWorldModified.pdf"));
            PdfContentByte canvas = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Hello people!"), 250, 750, 0);
            pdfStamper.close();
            pdfReader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, can you try setting the image sequence to true, as follows

```
writer.setStrictImageSequence(true);
```

Also, can we see some code you have written just to see the problem?
Cheers!